# Are these two sentences equal, about history and sources? - Why was this closed?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

I beg for your forgiveness if ['to make use of' vs 'to base on'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33771/8712), but I would like to request its reopening. While it's from my law preparation book, my question concerns English, so why was it 'closed as off-topic'? Would someone please advise how to improve or emend it?

For example, user Tyler James Young comments:

> the two are grammatically attached to different subjects, namely sources (in the passage) and a history (in the answer)

I don't understand this, because both sentences do feature 'history' as the subject?

Answer (score 2):

What does this part of your question mean?

> The answer is no.

The answer to *what* is no?

You have a passage, you have a (d). We don't even know what the question is.

You're not asking about English, or meanings of words, **you are asking why the answer to a question you haven't provided is or is not (d)**, and that's the crux of your problem.

Similarly, on [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33772): *Would someone please explain why (e) isn't assumed for the bolded?* is NOT a question about English.

#### You need to disassociate your questions here with the questions and answers in the book you are working through.

---

> If a historian makes fair use of a writ, then the historian's use is based on the writ?

This is the kind of question that might interest the legal community, but it's not the kind of question that would interest the English learner. "Fair use" is a legal term, and *based on* is so nebulous in meaning that it's just about impossible to answer this question.

I am strongly opposed to reopening either of these questions.